# SQL Query to pull the last four dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and trying to pull the 4 most recent order dates in a `OrderDate` column for certain members. I am not sure how to code for this.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've not provided any sample data, or indeed anything that could be used to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Order by date in descending order, and limit the number of rows to 4, like this:

```
select top 4 order_date from orders order by order_date desc
```

Optimizer will figure out that you have a limit, and optimize your query to avoid sorting the entire table. If order_date column is indexed, query optimizer would use index to get you four dates without going to the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something similar to this:

```
select top 4 o.OrderDate
from Members m
inner join Orders o
on m.ID = o.MemberID
where <your certain members criteria>
order by o.OrderDate desc
```

Comment: I guess it should, the reason I'm saying this is because this is just an approximate answer based on guessing your tables structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this (you didn't provide table structure, so this is just pseudo-code).

1. Create empty table TempOrders to store top orders for each member
2. Open Cursor to go through all member Ids
3. For each @MemberId insert into TempOrders select top 4 * from orders where MemberId = @MemberId order by OrderDate desc
4. your result is in TempOrders table